# Is it possible to add a new <td> instance to a <tr> row with bs4?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, edit

I want to edit a table of an .htm file, which roughly looks like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
  parameter A
  </td>
  <td>
  value A
  </td>  
 <tr/>
 <tr>
  <td>
  parameter B
  </td>
  <td>
  value B
  </td>  
 <tr/>
 ...
</table>
```

I made a preformatted template in Word, which has nicely formatted style="" attributes. I insert parameter values into the appropreatte tds from a poorly formatted .html file (This is the output from a scientific program). My job is to automate the creation of html tables so that they can be used in a paper, basically.

This works fine, while the template has empty td instances in a tr. But when I try create additional tds inside a tr (over which I iterate), I get stuck. The .append and .append_after methods for the rows just overwrite existing td instances. I need to create new tds, since I want to create the number of columns dynamically and I need to iterate over a number of up to 5 unformatted input .html files.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('template.htm') as template:
    template = BeautifulSoup(template)

template = template.find('table')
lines_template = template.findAll('tr')

    for line in lines_template:
        newtd = line.findAll('td')[-1]
        newtd['control_string'] = 'this_is_new'
        line.append(newtd)
```

=> No new tds. The last one is just overwritten. No new column was created.

I want to copy and paste the last td in a row, because it will have the correct style="" for that row. Is it possible to just copy a bs4.element with all the formatting and add it as the last td in a tr? If not, what module/approach should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the attributes by assigning to the `attrs`:

```
data = '''<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="color:red;">
  parameter A
  </td>
  <td style="color:blue;">
  value A
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="color:red;">
  parameter B
  </td>
  <td style="color:blue;">
  value B
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for i, tr in enumerate(soup.select('tr'), 1):
    tds = tr.select('td')

    new_td = soup.new_tag('td', attrs=tds[-1].attrs)
    new_td.append('This is data for row {}'.format(i))

    tr.append(new_td)

print(soup.table.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td style="color:red;">
   parameter A
  </td>
  <td style="color:blue;">
   value A
  </td>
  <td style="color:blue;">
   This is data for row 1
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style="color:red;">
   parameter B
  </td>
  <td style="color:blue;">
   value B
  </td>
  <td style="color:blue;">
   This is data for row 2
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, that already helped very much. If you could help me one more time, I'd be very grateful.

The problem is, that the tds are a bit more complex and vary in their overall structure slightly. 

Example: 
```
<td width='...' style=''...'  height:'...'>
  <p class='...' align='...' style='...''>
   <span style=''...''>
       Empirical formula<o:p></o:p>
   </span>
  </p>
</td>
```
Do I have to somehow create and append subtags recursively with .findChildren, or is it possible to just get the string of the whole td, make it a bs4 object and append that?

Comment: @J.Doe This comment section isn't good place to ask additional questions. Open new question, where you write your problem, your inputs and expected outputs.